# Having issues retriving data from my database to the users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying display all courses from my course model to the users, but seems i am getting it wrong.

here is my code;

views.py

```
 def course_list(request, category_slug=None):
       category = None
       categories = Category.objects.all()
       courses = Courses.objects.filter(available=True)
       if category_slug:
          category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
          courses = courses.filter(category=category)
       return render(request,'courses/content/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories':     categories, 'courses': courses})

def course_detail(request, id, slug):
    course = get_object_or_404(Courses, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    return render(request, 'courses/content/detail.html', {'course': course})
```

here is the code for my list.html

```
{%block content %}
<section id="about-home">
  <h2>Courses</h2>
</section>

<!-- courses section starts  -->
<section id="course">
  <h1>Our Amazing Courses</h1>
  <p>Replenish man have thing gathering lights yielding shall you</p>
  
  <div class="course-box">
        {% for course in courses %}
        <div onclick="window.location.href='{{ course.get_absoule.url}}';" class="courses">
            <img 
            src="{% if courses.cover %}{{ courses.cover.url }} {% else %} {% static 'images/c3.jpg' %}{% endif %}" 
            alt="{{ courses.name }}" />
        <div class="details">
            <span>{{courses.updated}}</span>
            <a href="{{ course.get_absolute_url }}"></a>
            <h6>{{courses.name}}</h6>
            <div class="star">
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="far fa-star"></i>
            <span>(23)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cost">${{courses.price_display}}</div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</section>

{%endblock content%}
```

the above codes is for my views.py and list.html

Comment: show your errors

Comment: Not actually getting errors, but the courses cover and details are not displaying as i wanted.